# On 2 crossed modules

Tags: gr.group-theory, higher-category-theory, crossed-modules

Let $(G,H,\alpha,\tau)$ and $(H,J,\alpha',\tau')$ be two crossed modules of groups. It is given that $Kernel(\tau) \cap Image(\tau')$ =$e$. For every $h\in H$ does there always exist a $j_h \in J$ such that
$\tau'(j_h).h \in $ $Kernel(\tau)$ ?

Notations are as follows:

$G,H,J$ are groups.

(1)  $\tau :H\rightarrow G$,

(2) $\alpha :G\rightarrow Aut(H)$

(3) $\tau': J\rightarrow H$

(4) $\alpha':H\rightarrow Aut(J)$

where  (1),(2),(3) and (4) are group homomorphisms such that
  (1),(2) and (3),(4) satisfy the usual compatibility conditions of a  crossed module respectively.

Comment: What is the notation $\tau'(j_h).h$ mean?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik it is the product in the group H

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_module uses . notation to mean something else... Thanks for clarification though there was no confusion... :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik you are welcome

Comment: This will fail whenever $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are the inclusions of normal subgroups and $J$ is a proper subgroup, i.e. $J\triangleleft H\trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. thanks for the comment. I am verifying it.

Comment: @ArnaudD. can you please elaborate a little bit ?

Comment: Well, $\ker(\tau)=\{e\}$ since $\tau$ is just an injection, and then $\tau'(j_h)\cdot h\in \ker(\tau)$ iff $h\in J$ and $j_h=h^{-1}$. So this will fail for all $h$ that are not in $J$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks ... and sorry for asking silly questions.

Comment: @ArnaudD What can be a sufficient condition  on those 2 crossed modules  so that for any $h \in H$ we can always find a $j_h \in J$ such that $\tau'(j_h).h \in Kernel(\tau)$

Comment: @ArnaudD. For example one trivial sufficient condition is when  $Kernel(\tau)$ is trivial and $\tau'$ is surjective . Does their exist some non trivial sufficient condition ?

Comment: It's equivalent to $H$ being isomorphic to $\tau'(J)\times \ker(\tau)$ (wich implies that $\tau(H)$ is isomorphic to $\tau'(J)$).

Comment: I@ArnaudD. Thanks..  is it a necessary and sufficient condition or is it only sufficient condition?